# "xsl:for-each" not working when first row is empty

Tags: xml, xslt

Like in title. When first element in XML for-each is empty, for-each not working.

```
<Uwaga>
  <linia></linia>
  <linia></linia>
  <linia>PLEASE SEND US BACK SIGNED COPY OF THIS INVOICE</linia>
</Uwaga>
```

I get values

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <xsl:for-each select="Uwaga/linia">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </fo:block>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </fo:table-cell>
```

And result is empty = not working. Any idea why ?
I use FOP 0.94.
When in first tag linia is value, for-each working normal.

Comment: Hi Waldek, it would be useful to have the entire XSLT document so we can reproduce.

Comment: Can you give a bit details as to what "not working" means? Is the issue that the xsl-fo is not being produced as expected? Or is it actually that the creation of the pdf from xsl-fo is not giving you the output you expect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following works with Xalan and Saxon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fo="http://www.example.com/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:for-each select="Uwaga/linia">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </fo:block>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:table-cell xmlns:fo="http://www.example.com/">
    <fo:block/>
    <fo:block/>
    <fo:block>PLEASE SEND US BACK SIGNED COPY OF THIS INVOICE</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: In Xalan works. I think its problem with this version FOP and I looking for way to workaround this.

Comment: You can't compare xalan (xsl stylesheet transform processor) to fop (formatting objects processor). We need to see the fo output that you get. If that looks the same then fop should produce the same output. If it's different, we must check the xsl and so.